# How to replace string with multiple semicolons and special characters using sed in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a string `"&#99;&#111;&#110;&#102;&#105;&#103;"`
and want to replace with
`"&#115;&#101;&#114;&#118;&#101;&#114;"`
using sed in Linux. I tried the below one. But It did not work.

```
sed -i "s#$"&#99;&#111;&#110;&#102;&#105;&#103;"#$"&#115;&#101;&#114;&#118;&#101;&#114;"#g" setup.xml-->
```

How can I do that? If not sed other options are fine too.

```
before "&#99;&#111;&#110;&#102;&#105;&#103;"
after "&#115;&#101;&#114;&#118;&#101;&#114;"
```

Comment: Could some one help me how to format my question?

Comment: Show the before and after strings in your original post.

Comment: @Kumar here are some links that may help you with the formatting of your questions: [How to format your questions using markdown or HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What's "the below one" and what didn't work?  just looking for more detail.

Comment: I tried to add before and after strings in my original post. as before and after string are xml decoded characters, it is not accepting as it is. so I put xml comment block.

Comment: This one did not work. sed -i "s#$"&#99;&#111;&#110;&#102;&#105;&#103;"#$"&#115;&#101;&#114;&#118;&#101;&#114;"#g" server_https_connector.xml

Comment: Why do you use `#` as delimiter for sed when your string clearly contains this character? The canonical sed form for substitute is `s/search/replace/flags`

Comment: `It did not work` is the worst possible problem statement. Imagine taking your car to the garage asking for it to be repaired and just telling the mechanic `It did not work`. [edit] your question to tell us in what way `It did not work` (wrong output, no output, error messages, etc.) so we can help you.

Comment: Ed Morton, Sorry about that "It did not work" statement. The one I tried did not replace the string. But no errors/output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One example:

```
sed 's/"&#99;&#111;&#110;&#102;&#105;&#103;"/"\&#115;\&#101;\&#114;\&#118;\&#101;\&#114;"/'  setup.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

The replacement string has characters with special meaning in sed such as ; # and &. These will all need to be escaped and so:

```
sed -n 's/"&#99;&#111;&#110;&#102;&#105;&#103;"/"\&\#115\;\&\#101\;\&\#114\;\&\#118\;\&\#101\;\&\#114\;"/p' <<< '"&#99;&#111;&#110;&#102;&#105;&#103;"'
```